# Ruby Merge 2 XML files with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

Alright so I have a small issue that I have never run into before and I am stuck. I have two XML files that I need to merge into one.

The first XML files is Product.xml which contains a list of sodas and here is an example:

```
<Soda_List>
  <Soda>
    <UPC>8675309</UPC>
    <Name>Coke</Name>
  </Soda>
  <Soda>
    <UPC>4283123</UPC>
    <Name>Yoohoo</Name>
  </Soda>
</Soda_List>
```

The second XML file is Ingredients.xml and it is a bit tricky... Each product has multiple ingredients. The file looks like:

```
<Soda_List>
  <Nutrients>
   <UPC>8675309</UPC>
   <Name>Calories</Name>
  </Nutrients>
  <Nutrients>
   <UPC>8675309</UPC>
   <Name>Fat</Name>
  </Nutrients>
  <Nutrients>
   <UPC>4283123</UPC>
   <Name>Sugar</Name>
  </Nutrients>
 </Soda_List>
```

I am using Ruby-2.2.4 and Nokogiri. The issue is that each product has multiple separate ingredients. I am trying to merge these ingredients by UPC. As each ingredient is matched to a UPC and each UPC is unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest converting the xml files into a ruby object, then do the merging, and at last do the xml serialization.

```
require 'nokogiri'

s1 = '''<Soda_List>
<Soda>
  <UPC>8675309</UPC>
  <Name>Coke</Name>
</Soda>
......
</Soda_List>'''

s2 = '''<Soda_List>
<Nutrients>
  <UPC>8675309</UPC>
  <Name>Calories</Name>
</Nutrients>
<Nutrients>
......
</Soda_List>'''

doc1 = Nokogiri::XML(s1)
doc2 = Nokogiri::XML(s2)

sodas = {}

doc1.xpath('//Soda').each do |soda|
  sodas[soda.at_xpath('./UPC').text] = {name: soda.at_xpath('./Name').text, nutrients: []}
end

doc2.xpath('//Nutrients').each do |nutrient|
  upc = nutrient.at_xpath('./UPC').text
  name = nutrient.at_xpath('./Name').text

  sodas[upc][:nutrients].push(name) if sodas.has_key?(upc)
end
```

and the values of the variable "sodas" would look likes this

```
{"8675309"=>{:name=>"Coke", :nutrients=>["Calories", "Fat"]}, "4283123"=>{:name=>"Yoohoo", :nutrients=>["Sugar"]}}
```

Comment: This is pretty close to what I have been looking for, however, it seems to lose the structure of the XML files when I try to build the new XML.

Comment: @CodeHard take my code as a sample, you can build up the structure in ruby you wants.